# How many unique BST's from n distinct integers? - Still not clear to me

Tags: algorithm

*If someone thinks i should edit the question... just suggest to me how to edit it and I'll go ahead and do it. just please don't be insulting.*

I saw a post with the same question, and followed a link.
I tried to understand the explanation, but it still confused me.

Here is the snippet of code. Can someone explain how exactly it works?

```
int number_of_trees(int n)
{
    int i, j;
    // Table to store results of subproblems
    int Trees[n+1];

    // Initialize first two values in table
    Trees[0] = Trees[1] = 1;

    for (i=2; i<=n; i++)
    {
        Trees[i] = 0;
        for (j=0; j<i; j++)
            Trees[i] += Trees[j] * Trees[i-j-1];
    }
    return Trees[n];
}
```

Comment: You can edit by clicking the "edit" link above this comment. You can always edit your own posts. Over 2000 reputation points you can even edit others..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we have `n` distinct integers `1, 2, ..., n`, then, if the root is `1`, we have reduced the problem to counting how many possibilities of building the right subtree we have (because the left subtree will be empty, nothing is smaller than 1). So far we have:

```
Trees[n] = Trees[n - 1] + ...
```

If the root is `2`, then the left subtree has to be `1`, and again we have to deal with the right subtree. We add this to our formula as well:

```
Trees[n] = Trees[n - 1] + Trees[n - 2] + ...
```

If the root is `3`, we have two possibilities for the left subtree: it can either be `2` with a left child of `1`, or `1` with a right child of `2`. Then, for **each** of these two possibilities, we can build the right subtree out of the remaining `n - 3` elements:

```
Trees[n] = Trees[n - 1] + Trees[n - 2] + Trees[2] * Trees[n - 3] + ...
```

If you continue this reasoning, and define `T[0] = T[1] = 1`, you get the formula:

```
Trees[n] = sum{i = 0 to n - 1} of Trees[i] * Trees[n - i - 1]
```

Because for each root `r`, you can build the left subtree out of the elements smaller than `r`, and for each of those possibilities of building the left subtree, you have the possibilities of building the right subtree out of the remaining elements. So you multiply the two, and get the answer for a fixed root. Sum the answers for all fixed roots and you get your final answer.

Your code implements this:

1. First, we set `Trees[0] = Trees[1] = 1`. This means that there is only one BST with 0 nodes and also only 1 with 1 node.
2. The first `for` loop then iterates up until `n`. This is needed, because our formula reuses previous values, so we compute these values botttom up.
3. The inner `for` loop applies the formula: there are `Trees[j]` way to build the left subtree if `j + 1` is the root and `Trees[i - j - 1]` ways to build the right subtree. These can be combined in any way, so you multiply them and get the answer for `i`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response!